# Follow path + soft body weird physics

Tags: path, soft-body

I am attempting to animate a ball that would roll on a plane.
The ball has soft body and I want it to follow a path.

Though after setting up this scene, I have my ball reacting in a bizarre way when starting the animation.
It violently moves back and forth and wobbles, definitely not rolling along the path as I expected.

'goal' is enabled and if I tweak the 'strenghts' to default '1', it would behave properly but the physics of the soft body won't show.
I suspect it is something along this line, but I cannot quite put my finger on it.

Does anyone experienced a similar problem or would have a recommendation?

I have been scratching my head for the whole day and fear for my capilarity...

Comment: From your description it sounds like there are conflicting influences at play.  Solution could be to parent the ball to an Empty, have another empty follow the path instead and parent the ball's empty to that. (child=ball empty)